# Propriedade de navegação do Entity Framework e WCF

Tags: entity-framework, wcf

Estou tentando implementar um serviço WCF que vai retornar um Model que também uso no Entity Framework. Quando o model tem uma propriedade `virtual` de navegação para associação com outro model o WCF não consegue fazer o parse do objeto e acaba retornando um erro falando que a conexão foi fechada.

Quando retiro a referência (propriedade de navegação) o parse é feito com sucesso e o objeto é retornado.

Qual o modo certo de fazer isso? Não posso retornar diretamente um Model? Como devo lidar com essas propriedades de associação no WCF?

Comment: Thiago, boa tarde, estou o mesmo problema, você conseguiu alguma solução?

Comment: Boa Tarde Ricardo e Bem Vindo a SoPt, os comentários são um campo de esclarecimento de duvidas, caso tenha uma duvida recomendo que faça uma nova pergunta para que a comunidade possa te ajudar diretamente.

Comment: @RicardoPulini, o `Entity Framework` precisa que a propriedade seja virtual para poder fazer o `LazyLoading`, porém não é desejavel colocar o `[DataMember]` em uma propriedade virtual, neste caso, o melhor a se fazer, é criar uma `DTO` e fazer o Mapeamento da `Entity` para a `DTO` e passar a trafegar a `DTO`.

Answer (score 0):

Você tentou retirar o `virtual` da propriedade de navegação, quando utilizamos o virtual, indica que estamos realizando com o Lazy Loading habilitado. Não tem muita lógica utilizar este conceito em aplicações Web, isto porque no cliente sempre precisaremos de todos os dados.

Neste artigo é explicado o conceito de Lazy Loading de forma mais detalhada:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210125135244/http://geekswithblogs.net/danemorgridge/archive/2010/05/04/entity-framework-4-wcf-amp-lazy-loading-tip.aspx)

Outros fator também comentado no artigo acima é a utilização de proxy do Entity Framework. Por padrão, o Entity Framework cria classes Proxy para realizar a conversão dos modelos para o banco de dados e isto atrapalha na hora da serialização dos dados para transmissão via WCF.

Verifique também este post do Stack Overflow gringo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884420/wcf-and-entities-framework-lazy-loading.

Espero ter ajudado